# How to synchronize local db value to Server(Hosting) db values in sql server 2008 R2?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How to Synchronize local database(datas) value to Server(Hosting) database values in SQL server 2008 R2? ex:from our client having a pc wen they are enterting entry it will insert kay ah...but in our concern keeping backup from server Hosting i mean IBM server...suppose client 
connecting internet connection means clicking single button event want to transfer OUR own server database also..can u got it
Is there such any option there? Please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Explain better please.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that use [Redgate Data compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) tools in order to synchronize data from one database to another database.

You can also use some query such as following query in order to determine deferent record in two database and synch them

```
USE Datbase1

INSERT INTO Schema1.Table1  (columns)
SELECT t1.Columns
FROM Datbase2.Schema2.Table2 t1
LEFT JOIN  Schema1.Table1 t2 ON t1.keyColumn = t2.Keycolumn
WHERE t2.keycolumn IS NULL
```

Comment: how i can  add that tool in my sqlserver..can explain briefly

Comment: I Edit my post. you can use link of redgate software.

Answer (score 0):

The RedGate will be costly for you. Use can use Open Source Database compare and sync tool as
  [Open DBDiff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/)

I have used it for my Live Databases compare with Local Database. Still today I have not found any issue.

Hope It will help you.

[image]

```
 Open DBDiff is an open source database schema comparison tool for SQL Server 2005/2008. 
It reports differences between two database schemas and provides a synchronization script to upgrade a database from one to the other.
```

Comment: it will help to transfer Database values local machine Databse into Server database right?

Comment: No It will never sync the data value. It will sync the Database schema , tables, procedures, functions, all other collations etc. For the Data Values you need to create Data Scripts manually with DATA as Generate Scripts on right click the database.

Comment: Its the alternative against the RedGate to compare the Databases. But The paid services are always better and provide some advance.